# How to fetch data from firestore in cloud function

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to fetch the user token from the firestore in a cloud function.

the user token was stored as follows:

```
void saveToken(String token) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("User tokens")
        .doc(userId)
        .set({'token': token});
  }
```

here is the goal.
When a message is created on the collection 'chat messages',
grab the "Chat id" value and the user who sends the message "User id".

query the collection "chat" using the "Chat id" value,
grab the "Job users data" value (this is an array with two objects, each object contains the users involved in the chat (userName,userId) ).

from the "Job users data", I need to grab the userId of the member who should be receiving the message.

query "User tokens" collection to grab the "token" value.
use the "token" value, to send a notification to

here is my cloud function:
as you see, I have hardcoded the token to see if I could send that device a notification.... that works perfect. now I need to to make this dynamic...

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { database } = require("firebase-admin");

// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
const tokens = ["JNKDNASNDAUIU324234....."];

admin.initializeApp();

// exports.onCreate = functions.firestore
//     .document("chat/{docId}")
//     .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
//       console.log(snapshot.data());
//       console.log("fake data");
//     });

exports.onChatMessageCreate = functions.firestore
    .document("chat messages/{docId}")
    .onCreate( (snapshot, context) => {
      console.log(snapshot.data());

     // fetch user to send message to
     // admin.database().ref("/")

      const payload = {
        // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
        notification: {title: snapshot.data()["userName"], body: snapshot.data()["Chat message"], sound: "default"},
        // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
        data: {click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", message: "Sample Push Message"},
      };

      try {
        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        console.log("NOTIFICATION SEND SUCCESSFULLY");
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("ERROR SENDING NOTIFICATION");
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
```

So all i need to know is how to query collections from a cloud function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to query a collection in Node.js. either through `then()` or `async/await`.

to  query using promise:

```html
const collectionRef = admin.firestore().collection("yourCollection");
 return collectionRef.get().then((collections) => {
//you can now use your collections here
});
```

using async/await:

```html
  const collectionRef = admin.firestore().collection("yourCollection");
    const collections = await collectionRef.get();
```

Comment: await/async does not work for me. I get the following:
/Users/juan/StudioProjects/mynotes/functions/index.js
  29:42  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Comment: How do I handle data from collections?

I tried the following but no luck

 const collectionRef = admin.firestore().collection("chat");
      collectionRef.get().then((collections) => {
        // you can now use your collections here
        data = collections.data;
      });

      console.log(data);

Comment: what are you trying to do with the list of chats?

Comment: query the collection "chat" using the "Chat id" value, grab the "Job users data" value (this is an array with two objects, each object contains the users involved in the chat (userName,userId) ).


from the "Job users data", I need to grab the userId of the member who should be receiving the message.

query "User tokens" collection to grab the "token" value. use the "token" value, to send a notification to


i been stuck on this for like 3 hours lol. about to start crying here anyminute lmao :( :(

Comment: what i only answered is your question `how to query collection using cloud function`. but if you have the chatId, you shouldn't be querying the entire collection. instead, query directly the document where the `id is your ChatId`.

Comment: I've implemented a chat feature in my app myself and the easiest thing to get the recipient Id is to include it in the chat so that you can catch it from the snapshot inside your cloud functions. query the user using the recipientId, get his token then send him a notification payload.

Comment: I created a new question with more detail, and using the info you provided:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74266961/how-to-handle-asyc-await-data-from-firebase-cloud-function